# Why is my nexus metadata.xml snapshot version incorrect?

Tags: maven, nexus, snapshot

This is my metadata. It's clearly incorrect, but I don't know why, so maven can't update download dependencies in my project.

```
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
   <groupId>com.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>test-sdk</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <versioning>
     <snapshot>
       <timestamp>20140130.175110</timestamp>
       <buildNumber>58</buildNumber>
     </snapshot>
     <lastUpdated>20140130175110</lastUpdated>
     <snapshotVersions>
       <snapshotVersion>
         <extension>jar</extension>
         <value>1.7.0-20140130.175109-57</value>
         <updated>20140130175110</updated>
       </snapshotVersion>
       <snapshotVersion>
         <extension>pom</extension>
         <value>1.7.0-20140130.175109-57</value>
         <updated>20140130175110</updated>
       </snapshotVersion>
     </snapshotVersions>
   </versioning>
 </metadata>
```

Comment: Are you having problems trying to download new SNAPSHOTs from Nexus or having problems uploading (mvn deploy) to it? If the problem is on downloading, I suggest you to run your build [with the -U flag](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-mavens-u-command-line).

Comment: I am having problem downloading, because build 58 doesn't exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why this happens, but I solved scheduling a Nexus task to "rebuild metadata" in "Scheduled Task" admin option. For now, this is a valid solution for me.

[image]

Additional information about how to fix the issue in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57524965/1654688)

Comment: I added a self explanatory image and updated the text

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. You might check your test-sdk's parent pom to see if any extra maven deploy plugin defined in.

Comment: Thanks. But this project doesn't have parent pom. Some other idea?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I used the Maven Deploy Plugin and the Nexus Staging Plugin simultaneously. Try skipping the Maven Deploy Plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <skip>true</skip>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks